# Finding minimal pattern(s) in a sequence

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, sequence

Is there an algorithm to find the minimal sequence(s) within a large sequence?

Without any prior knowledge of what those sequences would be?

For example, given the sequence {2,3,1,2,3,1}, it would return
{2,3,1}

Additionally, if there is a non-repeating sequence alongside it, i.e. {2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4}, that sequence would simply get ignored, and you would get
{2,3,1} {1,2,3,4}

And lastly, if there is a non-repeating sequence between, i.e.
{**2,3,1**,1,2,3,4,**2,3,1**}, you would also get {2,3,1} {1,2,3,4}

Any guidance in this area would be appreciated. I've been playing around with reg-ex's to try and get that to work, but am not sure if that is the best way to go, and even if so, have not been able to get a regex to perform that operation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How is `{1,2,3,4}` a repeating sequence in `{2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4}` ? It appears just once... The minimal repeating sequence I see here is `{1}`, because there's two ones next to each other. I really don't get what you're trying to get.

Comment: You can do this by customizing a [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

Comment: @Protectator its basically about identifying any patterns that you can find, and leaving any "non-patterns" alone. They are essentially, in the context of the problem i'm attempting to tackle, a "pattern that repeats once (the one time it occurs)". An alternative would be simply to return all patterns found ({2,3,1}), and then i would just pass through and find all elements that didnt match any patterns found

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub C++, although i'm familiar with most other common ones, so feel free to answer in any language, and i'm sure an equivalent can be written in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @Thomas's answer you are able to capture those non-repeating sequences within an alternation. It means if third capturing group is not empty then you have such sequences. Also I made middle `.*` pattern un-greedy:

```
((?:\d,)+)(.*?)\1+|((?:\d,)+)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/iW3gE9/1)

Update based on comments:

```
((?:\d,)+?)\1+$|((?:\d,)+)((?:\d,)*?)\2+|((?:\d,)+)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD1eL1/1)

Comment: Is there a way to further reduce? I.e. in https://regex101.com/r/iW3gE9/2, with example: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3, it returns 1,2,3,1,2,3, NOT 1,2,3?

Comment: That is fantastic. Haha will have to do some performance testing, seems to use a ton of steps, but you definitely did some regex magic there... probably a subject i need to learn a little better...

Comment: Beside lots of backtracks of the current regex, lazy quantifiers are like that: making engine to stop at each position to see if is able to continue with the next pattern. More steps, more CPU consuming. @jekelija

Comment: You should use `((?:\d+,)+?)\1+$|((?:\d+,)+)((?:\d+,)*?)\2+|((?:\d+,)+)` to allow numbers with multiple digits in the array

Answer (score 0):

Something like this `((?:\d,?)+)(.*)\1(.*)` could match repetitive sequences thanks to the back-reference to the capturing group, see [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT9hU7/1).

Comment: That seems like a great start. Thank you very much. However, it seems to have some trouble with identifying more than one pattern, i.e. https://regex101.com/r/zT9hU7/2.